# Count null fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to count how many fields are equal to null in mongodb?

I am not asking for how many times a field (with a concrete name) is null in a collection but rather how many fields (wildcard name) equal to null in a document. What I am trying to get is the average number of fields that equal to null in an entire collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4

`$objectToArray` to return all the key and values pairs in a doc followed by `$unwind` to flatten to multiple document each doc with a key value pair and `$group` across the entire collection to check all the field value for null and `$sum` to accumulate values.

`$cond` with query condition to output 1 when null or else 0. `$$ROOT` to access the whole document.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
  "arrayofkeyvalue":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$arrayofkeyvalue"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "count":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$arrayofkeyvalue.v",null]},1,0]}}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it and mongod 3.4.1 reports the following message "Unrecognized expression '$objectToArray'" . I've tried a simpler query: db.coll.aggregate([{"$project":{"arrayofkeyvalue":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"}}}]) and the error is the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes can you try latest 3.4 ? ObjectToArray a available from 3.4.4

Answer (score 1):

If you have data such as this:

[image]:

```
*{"_id":{"$oid":"572bb8222b288919b68adfa5"},
"tripduration":null,
"start station id":279,
"start station name":"Peck Slip & Front St",
"end station id":268,
"end station name":"Howard St & Centre St",
"bikeid":22820,
"usertype":"Customer",
"birth year":"","gender":0,
....
...
```

you can solve the problem with this code:

```
db.collection.find({$and: [{tripduration: null}, {tripduration: {$exists: true}}]}).count()
```